# How to delete a docker image in dockerhub with a particular tag or set of tags using CLI?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub, docker-api

I have docker images like this

```
user/image:1.0
user/image:2.0
user/image:2.1
.
.
user/image:2.9
user/image:3.0
```

I want to delete images from user/image:2.1 to user/image:2.9 USING CLI by calling docker api.

Basically I want to delete an image from CLI by calling api. The above case is an example.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it but this one is easier to remember than using the docker format/filter options.

`docker image rm user/image:2.{1..9}`

Comment: I mean to delete the images in the repository not local images. By api I mean dockerhub or private docker registry not docker daemon. Thanks